# QUnit mocking out Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, unit-testing, qunit

In my QUnit test I want to mock out autocomplete method (jQuery UI), but every time I'm runing test like:

```
test("Create_PassedContainer_RunsAutocompleteOnMatchingElement",function(){
    var $matchingInput = $('<input data-autocomplete-url="some"/>');
    var $dom = $('<div><input/></div>');
    $dom.append($matchingInput);
    var autocompleteWasCalled = false;
    $matchingInput.autocomplete = function(){ autocompleteWasCalled = true; };

    new Autocomplete($dom);

    ok(autocompleteWasCalled,"Should call autocomplete.");
});
```

I'm getting result:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'.
```

Code under test:

```
function Autocomplete($container) {
    var $self = this;

    this.Initialize = function($container) {
        $self.$container = $container;
        $self.$text = $('*[data-autocomplete-url]', $container);
        $self.$value = $('input[type="hidden"]', $container);

        $self.$text.autocomplete();
    };

    $self.Initialize($container);
};
```

Anything would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autocomplete is a plugin, try this:

```
var oldAutocomplete = $.fn.extend(true, {}, $.autocomplete);
$.autocomplete = function(){
    autocompleteWasCalled = true;
}

/// Other code...

$.fn.autocomplete = oldAutocomplete;
```